# How to get source of the website fastest as possible

Tags: java, php, c++, curl

Hello I would like to know how to get source of website in minimal time.

I am using PHP & CURL.

Is there any fasted/more efficient method?

Thx

Comment: You want to download the full sources of an existing website?

Comment: have a look at [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/)

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of the time taken to download an HTML document will be taken up by the network transfer. The libraries you use on the client aren't going to make a significant difference.

Comment: +1. Add that the html is not the source of a dynamic website ;)